# Pandas append() error with two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to append two or more dataframe and output the result to a csv, it shows like a waterfall format.

```
    dataset = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')
  for i in segment_dist:
      for j in step:
          print_msg = str(i) + ":" + str(j)
          print("\n",i,":",j,"\n")
          temp = pd.DataFrame(estimateRsq(dataset,j,i),columns=[print_msg])
          csv = csv.append(temp)
  csv.to_csv('output.csv',encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

estimateRsq() returns array. I think this much code snippet should be enough to help me out.

The format I am getting in output.csv is:
[image]

Please help, How can I shift the contents go up from index 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `df.append` documentation:

> Append rows of `other` to the end of this frame, returning a new
>   object. Columns not in this frame are added as new columns.

If you want to add column to the right, use `pd.concat` with `axis=1` (means horizontally):

```
list_of_dfs = [first_df, second_df, ...]
pd.concat(list_of_dfs, axis=1)
```

You may want to add parameter `ignore_index=True` if indexes in dataframes don't match.

Answer (score 1):

**Build a list of dataframes, then concatenate**

`pd.DataFrame.append` is expensive relative to `list.append` + a single call of `pd.concat`.

Therefore, you should aggregate to a list of dataframes and then use `pd.concat` on this list:

```
lst = []

for i in segment_dist:
    # do something
    temp = pd.DataFrame(...)
    lst.append(temp)

df = pd.concat(lst, ignore_index=True, axis=0)

df.to_csv(...)
```